# IIS7 welcome screen showing for site root requests

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

If you navigate to http://www.website.com/ you will see the IIS7 welcome screen.

If you navigate to http://www.website.com/?abcd123 (or any random querystring) you will see the correct site.

If you navigate to http://www.website.com/default.asp (which is also set as the default document) you will see the correct site.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

What is even more strange is that if I stop the web publishing service on the server, http://www.website.com/ still responds with the IIS7 welcome screen, but http://www.website.com/?randomquerystring gets a request timeout error (as it should).

I have check and rechecked:
Default document (default.asp only)
Custom error pages (disabled)
Output caching (turned off)
Cleared local browser cache
Tried the various URLs on multiple machines in 3 different locations and via proxify.com

The site is running in its own AppPool in integrated mode, .Net 2.0.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been fixed.

This was due to a 'corrupted cache store' on the firewall of my hosting company. It was not an IIS issue.

Comment: hi rory, can u pls lets us knw how u cleared ur 'corrupted cache store' on the firewall? we are facing the same issue now.

Comment: Hi viki, it was my hosting company who did this for me. All I did was put in a support request and they fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Rory , did you restart your application pool as well as the site. please restart once and also check for the authentication .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have restarted/recycled the application pool. Multiple times in fact. I have also created a new application pool and tested within that, with no change in outcome.